# Is there any Oracle built-in function to convert date format and how to exclude weekends from the logic

Tags: plsql

The below code gives me the output of current review date and the next review date. Here the current review date is fixed to today's date. 
I want to keep that as a user defined variable. I tried using the --> **ReviewDate = &enter_date;** but whichever format i put in the dialog box it gives me an error (i tried 08-06-2020, 06-08-2020, 08-Jun-2020, etc). Is there any built-in function in oracle which will convert the value I input to the correct system date which oracle will understand ?
Also, what should be the code if i want to exclude any weekends from my current logic ? Here the next review date is set to 6 months from current review date but i want my code to exclude the weekends from this.

Thanks!!

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    ReviewDate  workforce.Jdate%TYPE;

BEGIN
    ReviewDate := '08-06-2020';
    ReviewDate_New := add_months(ReviewDate, 6);

    dbms_output.put_line('Last Review Date: ' || '08-06-2020');
    dbms_output.put_line('Next Review Date: ' || ReviewDate_New);

END;
```

Comment: System date in Oracle doesn't have a specific format.  Internally is only 7 bytes.
The format is only for application presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ANSI format for a date literal is DATE 'YYYY-NN-DD' so:

```
ReviewDate := DATE '2020-06-08';
```

To avoid weekends you would have to check the day of the week returned by the `add_months` function and then increment the date accordingly. `to_char` with the 'D' format returns you a number 1-7 for the day of the week, so something like:

```
CASE TO_CHAR(ReviewDate_New, 'D')
   WHEN 6 THEN 
      ReviewDate_New := ReviewDate_New + 2;
   WHEN 7 THEN 
      ReviewDate_New := ReviewDate_New + 1;
   ELSE
      NULL; -- Do nothing
END CASE;
```

This assumes that Saturdays and Sundays are day 6 and 7 in your database (it depends on NLS settings).